# Rails - Show additional fields if a specific field receives an input

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a fields_for inside a form_for in my Sale/new.html.erb that goes like that:

```
<%= form_for (@sale) do |s| %>

    <%= fields_for :fee, @sale.fee do |f| %>
        <p> Rent : <%= f.number_field :rent %> </p>
        <p> Number of POSs : <%= f.number_field :amt_pos %> </p>
    <% end %>

<%= s.submit %>     
<% end %>
```

And I need to show another field only if Number of POSs receives an input.

```
<p> POS Tax : <%= f.number_field :pos_tax %> </p>
```

I know I have to implement some JavaScript in order to perform this action dynamically, but I'm unable to figure it out on how to refer to that specific field

**EDIT:**
The marked answer works fine, but for Rails 5 (which was my case) you have to use turbo-links. Meaning you have to use

this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
```

instead of:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
```

Comment: Add an id into the <p> tag. For example, `<p id='number_of_pos'> Number of POSs : <%= f.number_field :amt_pos %> </p>`. Then in your javascript you would find it under `$("#number_of_pos")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your DOM like that :

```
<%= form_for (@sale) do |s| %>
    <%= fields_for :fee, @sale.fee do |f| %>
        <div>
            Rent : <%= f.number_field :rent %>
        </div>
        <div>
            Number of POSs : <%= f.number_field :amt_pos, class: "toggle-at-input", :"data-toggle-container" => "container-to-display" %>
        </div>
        <div id="container-to-display" style="display:none;">
            POS's Tax : <%= f.number_field :pos_tax %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= s.submit %>     
<% end %>
```

And in jQuery :

```
<script>
    $(document).on('ready', function(){
        $('input.toggle-at-input').on('keyup', function(){
            var $input = $(this),
                $container = $("#" + $input.data('toggle-container'));

            ($input.val() != "") ? $container.fadeIn() : $container.fadeOut(); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code allows you to display your input if the value of the given field is not empty.

I have not test this code but it should works :)

Comment: This worked, but the real problem was that I was not using turbo-links

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best solution, but one way to go about it would to be attach a jQuery event listen to your number of POS input field that looks for a change in input value, and then, if the value is something you're looking for, unhide your third field (i.e., change the css from `display: none;` to something else.

So, if you give an ID to your number of POS input field and your tax field you can have something like this:

```
$("#num-of-pos" ).on("input", function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $("#pos-tax").css({ "display" : "inline-block" });
  }
});
```